# Why is #include <iostream> not working on VS-code for me?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile a C++ project in Visual Studio Code but I get an error on the `#include <iostream>` that says: cannot open source file "iostream". The quick fix is to add C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0 as an include path.

When I try that, I get the error: cannot open source file "bits/c++config.h" (dependency of "iostream"). The quick fix is adding C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 as an include path. When I do that, there's no error on the header but there are errors on seemingly random parts of the code.

I've looked up solutions but none of them seem to work.

[Here's a screenshot of where the error marks are (ignore that I'm a dirty namespace user)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP1Rf.png)

Here are a few of the error messages:

using: variable "using" is not a type name

std: expected a ';'

cout: identifier "cout" is undefined

c: expression must have integral type

Comment: This is Visual Studio Code, _not_ Visual Studio (VS).  Based on the errors, it seems you're probably using a C compiler, not C++.

Comment: Do you want to compile with the mingw compiler or with the Microsoft compiler?

Comment: Why does your file have no extension?

Comment: You should most definitely NOT add different compiler's header location to your include path .

Comment: VS Code has tons a prerequsites you need to take care of [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) Have you completed all of those?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there was a problem in the configuration of the C ++ compiler.
try uninstalling the extensions and the compiler and reinstalling them following the [official microsoft guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp):

- link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: Whilst "read the manual" is probably the right answer to the question an answer that is mostly just a link is fragile as when the link inevitably breaks (Microsoft likes to move things around and break links) the answer becomes useless